# Getting associated objects count with condition in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, associations

I have the following models Merchant, Offer and GiftCards. I want to get all associated offers and gift_cards with certain conditions.

Association between them:

merchant.rb

```
has_many :offers
has_many :gift_cards
```

gift_card.rb:

```
belongs_to :merchant
```

offer.rb:

```
belongs_to :merchant
```

To get the count directly I am able to do

```
Merchant.pluck(
    :id, Arel.sql('COUNT(offers.id)'), Arel.sql('MAX(offers.id)'),
     Arel.sql('COUNT(gift_cards.id)'), Arel.sql('MAX(gift_cards.id)')
 )
```

But the problem statement is that I have an array of eligible_offer_ids and eligible_gift_card_ids. I want to get a merchant's eligible_offers / eligible_gift_cards count.

I can do something similar to the following code to get the count.

```
merchant.offer_ids & eligible_offer_ids
```

But is there a way I modify the query to get eligible_offers instead of all offers in the merchant.

Something similar to the below query.

```
    Merchant.pluck(
    :id, Arel.sql('COUNT(eligible_offer_ids.id)'), Arel.sql('MAX(eligible_offer_ids.id)'),
     Arel.sql('COUNT(eligible_gift_card_ids.id)'), 
     Arel.sql('MAX(gift_eligible_gift_card_id.id)')
 )
```

Comment: Can you paste the model/reltationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Merchant.joins(:offers, :gift_cards)
  .select('merchants.id, COUNT(gift_cards) as offer_count, 
           COUNT(gift_cards) as gift_card_count')
  .where(offers: { id: eligible_offer_ids }, 
         gift_cards: { id: eligible_gift_cards_ids })
  .group(:id)
```

This will return an ActiveRecord_Relation of the merchant's ids, offer_counts, and gift_card_counts where eligible offers and gift card ids are in those arrays. You can then iterate through for whatever you need :D